# How to put a vertical separator in the middle of span4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap framework and I'm trying to put a vertical separator between three span4.

So I coded [this](http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/3/)

To see the result is more clear if you enter [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/3/embedded/result/)

**CSS**

```
.span4 {
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
}
.span4:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">Hello</div>
        <div class="span4">Stack</div>
        <div class="span4">Overflow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

As you can see the border is at the end of the span, but not in the middle of them... 
I would also like to have the line with different length than span4 and vertical centered.

Any advice or tip would be appreciated.

If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want? Do you want to use a `border` (which will always be the full length of the relevant side) or a character (`|`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to fiddle with the Bootstrap margins. The default Bootstrap style adds a `margin-left` of 20px to `[class*="span"]` elements, meaning the display is:

```
[margin][element] [margin][element] [margin][element]
```

In order to get a border directly between those margins you'll need to be a bit hacky and introduce a new divider between the `.span4` and the content within.

```
   <div class="span4">
        <div class="inner">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="inner">
            Stack
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.row-fluid .span4 {
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    height: 400px;
    margin:0;
}
.span4:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
.inner {
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: grey;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a very rough mock up: http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/5/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create a background image with one pixel height and assign it to the containing div and make it repeat-y. However I came up with this:

```
.span4 {
    position: relative;
}
.span4:first-child::after {
    content: "";
}
.span4::after {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 384px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to remove your border

Answer (score 1):

Hi better way is using a first-child, because last-child is not supported by IE. So..this is James modified code:

**CODE:**

```
.row-fluid .span4 {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    height: 400px;
    margin:0;
}
.span4:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.inner {
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: grey;
    height:100%;
}
```

**DEMO**
    http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/40/